# 500 error in move_uploaded_files()

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am not sure what the error is and I am unable to read the error since I am being redirected to 500 error and not able to judge the error, here is my code -

**html to send the files:**

```
  <form action="#" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-validate' id="add-image" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="select" class="control-label">Product</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" name="type" id="type" class="input-xlarge" value="image">
        <input type='hidden' name="issubmit" value="1">
        <select name="product" id="product" class='input-xxlarge'>
<?php
  $testsql = "SELECT product_id,UPPER(concat(product_code,' - ',product_name,' - ',category_name,' - ', subcat_name)) as product_name FROM category ca,product pro,subcategory su where su.subcat_id=pro.subcat_id and su.category_id=ca.category_id ORDER BY product_id ";
  $testresult = mysql_query($testsql);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($testresult))
  {
    echo "<option value=\"". $row['product_id']."\">". $row['product_name']. "</option>";
  }
?>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="textfield" class="control-label"></label>
      <div class="controls">
        <div class="check-demo-col" style="width:175px;">
          <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="../upload/sample.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 2px;"></div>
            <div>
              <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select main-view</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name='imagefile[]' /></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="check-demo-col" style="width:175px;">
          <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="../upload/sample.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div>
              <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select left-view</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name='imagefile[]' /></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="check-demo-col" style="width:175px;">
          <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="../upload/sample.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div>
              <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select right-view</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name='imagefile[]' /></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="check-demo-col" style="width:175px;">
          <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="../upload/sample.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div>
              <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select top-view</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name='imagefile[]' /></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="check-demo-col" style="width:175px;">
          <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"><img src="../upload/sample.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
            <div>
              <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Select bottom-view</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name='imagefile[]' /></span>
              <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label for="select" class="control-label">Status</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <select name="status" id="status" class='input-large'>
          <option value="active">Active</option>
          <option value="disabled">Disabled</option>
          <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" name="submit">
      <button type="button" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**and my php is:**

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
  { 

    if(isset($_REQUEST['product']))
    {
      $product=$_REQUEST['product'];
      // echo $product;        
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['status']))
    {
      $status=$_REQUEST['status'];
      // echo $status;        
    }

    $target = "../upload/"; 
    $count=0;
    foreach ($_FILES['imagefile']['name'] as $filename) 
    {
      $temp=$target;
      $tmp=$_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'][$count];

      $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
      // echo $extension;
      $temp=$temp.basename($product.'_'.($count + 1).'.'.$extension);
      move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);
      // echo $temp;

      //This gets all the other information from the form 
      $image=($_FILES['imagefile']['name']); 
      if($image[$count])
      {
        // $insert=mysql_query("INSERT INTO image VALUES (DEFAULT,'$product','$temp','$image[$count]','$status')") ;
      }
      $count=$count + 1;
      $temp='';
      $tmp='';
    }
  }
```

**I get the following error:**

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error. More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

I'm not able to read the error log and `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` is not working.

Just to check, I commented/removed the  `move_uploaded_file($tmp,$temp);` and found no error with the format or code. It is the `move_uploaded_files()` that is giving the trouble and I have tried adding

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

to `.htaccess` and found no help. The file sizes are anyway less than 1MB, so this is not at all an issue, I guess.

Comment: And what do your error logs say...

Comment: `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.`

not able to read,
`error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` not working

Comment: Not from the page, from your actual `error.log` and `error.log` (apache & php)

Comment: how can i get that? any help?

Comment: why `foreach ($_FILES['imagefile']['name'] as $filename)`??

Comment: array for multiple images @sgt to upload and send them to db as well so.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_FILES)` and see what is the structure of data you are getting.

Comment: foreach() is not at all an issue, my localhost is good with that,i am getting the desired output there,but not in server due to some other error,still i checked by removing foreach() and tried uploading single file, same error!! @sgt

Comment: Sidenote: The original `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO_MySQL`. Plus;  nice SQL injection you've got there. Escape _all_ values before inserting them into a query. Use PDO's prepared statements.

Comment: Do you have FTP access to your ISP? Is there a `logs/` folder in the folder _above_ the web root (`public_html`), with a `php.log` file or similar? Can you run `<?php header ('Content-Type: text/plain'); readfile ('../logs/php.log');` in your web root?

Comment: yes @NisseEngström i have the access and am seeing lot of folders maybe because i have list of clients website hosted as well,so i am pretty much confused with which is my log file and trying to upload(generate the error) again not creating any change in access time,so pretty much lost here

Answer (score 0):

The **isset()** function can only return either TRUE or FALSE but you are checking to see if it has the value of POST. By just having `isset($_POST['submit'])` in the if statement, you are checking to see if it is set to TRUE. To check if it is false, you would change it to `!isset($_POST['submit'])`.

The error log will be more precise as to the cause of the **500 error** message. I don't think the error in the if statement would have caused a **500 error**.

If you can't check error logs then, at the top of your PHP file add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```